# Method of Moment Estimator -- Uniform Dist

Tags: estimation, moments, method-of-moments

> Find the two method of moment estimators for $\theta$ given that $Y_i | \theta$ is distributed i.i.d U(0,$\theta$).

We know that E($Y_1$) = $\frac{\theta}{2}$ and Var($Y_1$) = $\frac{\theta^2}{12}$ .
E($X_i$) = $\mu_1$ = $\frac{\theta}{2}$

E($X_i^2$) = $\mu_2$ = $\mu^2$ + $\sigma^2$ = $\frac{\theta^2}{4}$ + $\frac{\theta^2}{12}$

Now we solve for $\theta$.

$2\mu_1$ = $\theta$

$\frac{3\theta^2}{12}$ + $\frac{\theta^2}{12}$ = $\frac{4\theta^2}{12}$

$\mu_2$ = $\frac{4\theta^2}{12}$

3$\mu_2$ = $\theta^2$

$\sqrt{3\mu_2}$ = $\theta$

$\hat{\theta}_{1}$ = $2m_1$

$\hat{\theta}_{2}$ = $\sqrt{3m_2}$

Where the $m_i$s are our sample moments.

Is this correct?

Comment: Where did $\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\hat{\theta}_2$ come from?  There's only one $\theta$.

Comment: Those are the two separate estimators. Both are estimating the $\theta$.

Comment: Did the problem specify estimators based on the first two moments?  Otherwise, there aren't "the two" method of moments estimators, you could use any moment to form a MOM estimator.  For example, you are using the second noncentral moment, but you could use the second central moment (the variance) to get $\hat{\theta}_2 = \sqrt{12} \sigma$.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209328/second-moment-of-beta-distribution/209331#209331